# Mongoose find/update subdocument

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following schemas for the document **Folder**:

```
var permissionSchema = new Schema({
    role: { type: String },
    create_folders: { type: Boolean },
    create_contents: { type: Boolean }
});

var folderSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: string },
    permissions: [ permissionSchema ]
});
```

So, for each Page I can have many permissions. In my CMS there's a panel where I list all the folders and their permissions. The admin can edit a single permission and save it.

I could easily save the whole **Folder** document with its permissions array, where only one permission was modified. But I don't want to save all the document (the real schema has much more fields) so I did this:

```
savePermission: function (folderId, permission, callback) {
    Folder.findOne({ _id: folderId }, function (err, data) {
        var perm = _.findWhere(data.permissions, { _id: permission._id });                

        _.extend(perm, permission);

        data.markModified("permissions");
        data.save(callback);
    });
}
```

but the problem is that **perm** is always **undefined**! I tried to "statically" fetch the permission in this way:

```
var perm = data.permissions[0];
```

and it works great, so the problem is that Underscore library is not able to query the permissions array. So I guess that there's a better (and workgin) way to get the subdocument of a fetched document.

Any idea?

*P.S.: I solved checking each item in the data.permission array using a "for" loop and checking data.permissions[i]._id == permission._id but I'd like a smarter solution, I know there's one!*

Answer (score 143, accepted):

So as you note, the default in mongoose is that when you "embed" data in an array like this you get an `_id` value for each array entry as part of it's own sub-document properties. You can actually use this value in order to determine the index of the item which you intend to update. The MongoDB way of doing this is the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) operator variable, which holds the "matched" position in the array:

```
Folder.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": folderId, "permissions._id": permission._id },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "permissions.$": permission
        }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

That [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#model_Model.findOneAndUpdate) method will return the modified document or otherwise you can just use `.update()` as a method if you don't need the document returned. The main parts are "matching" the element of the array to update and "identifying" that match with the [positional `$`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/) as mentioned earlier.

Then of course you are using the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/) operator so that **only** the elements you specify are actually sent "over the wire" to the server. You can take this further with ["dot notation"](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/document/#document-dot-notation) and just specify the elements you actually want to update. As in:

```
Folder.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": folderId, "permissions._id": permission._id },
    { 
        "$set": {
            "permissions.$.role": permission.role
        }
    },
    function(err,doc) {

    }
);
```

So this is the flexibility that MongoDB provides, where you can be very "targeted" in how you actually update a document.

What this does do however is "bypass" any logic you might have built into your "mongoose" schema, such as "validation" or other "pre-save hooks". That is because the "optimal" way is a MongoDB "feature" and how it is designed. Mongoose itself tries to be a "convenience"  wrapper over this logic. But if you are prepared to take some control yourself, then the updates can be made in the most optimal way.

So where possible to do so, keep your data "embedded" and don't use referenced models. It allows the atomic update of both "parent" and "child" items in simple updates where you don't need to worry about concurrency. Probably is one of the reasons you should have selected MongoDB in the first place.

Comment: ehi! great code thank you! However, if I had to query a document, change a field and save it againg, it would be ok for me, I didn't want to save an entire object coming from the User Interface. But being able to query a document and save just one field (even a field of just one subdocument) is really powerful! I really have to dig in the $ operator.

Comment: When I'm using this to update the entire subdoc (rather than just one field) this seems to be removing the `_id` property of the subdocument that MongoDB gave it for being part of an array. This is probably because I removed the `_id` property from the postman request body, so maybe I just need to make sure it's in the request body? Seems weird that MongoDB is letting me completely overwrite the whole object, including removing the `_id` property. It doesn't do that on parent objects (effectively a PATCH request instead of PUT). Any workaround?

Comment: @DarkoRomanov did you find a way to update some **dynamic fields** coming from the User Interface?

Answer (score 42):

In order to validate subdocuments when updating in Mongoose, you have to 'load' it as a Schema object, and then Mongoose will automatically trigger validation and hooks.

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  // ...
  addresses: [addressSchema],
});
```

If you have an array of subdocuments, you can fetch the desired one with the `id()` method provided by Mongoose. Then you can update its fields individually, or if you want to update multiple fields at once then use the `set()` method.

```
User.findById(userId)
  .then((user) => {
    const address = user.addresses.id(addressId); // returns a matching subdocument
    address.set(req.body); // updates the address while keeping its schema       
    // address.zipCode = req.body.zipCode; // individual fields can be set directly

    return user.save(); // saves document with subdocuments and triggers validation
  })
  .then((user) => {
    res.send({ user });
  })
  .catch(e => res.status(400).send(e));
```

Note that you don't really need the `userId` to find the User document, you can get it by searching for the one that has an address subdocument that matches `addressId` as follows:

```
User.findOne({
  'addresses._id': addressId,
})
// .then() ... the same as the example above
```

Remember that in MongoDB the subdocument is saved **only** when the parent document is saved.

Read more on the topic on the [official documentation](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html).

Comment: This helped me too! I would have marked this as a correct solution 

Comment: This is really helpful. After searching for 4 hours, I finally found this answer.

Comment: Do we get all address collection  throw User.findById(userId) and then try to filter them by using user.address.id(addressId)? I am afraid that if the address subdocument array is very big, we load very many unnecessary items just to update one. Please, correct if I am wrong.

Comment: This was really helpful after wasting a whole day tring to make it work with mongosh.

Answer (score 7):

If you don't want separate collection, just embed the permissionSchema into the folderSchema.

```
var folderSchema = new Schema({
    name: { type: string },
    permissions: [ {
        role: { type: String },
        create_folders: { type: Boolean },
        create_contents: { type: Boolean }
    } ]
});
```

If you need separate collections, this is the best approach:

You could have a Permission model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var PermissionSchema = new Schema({
  role: { type: String },
  create_folders: { type: Boolean },
  create_contents: { type: Boolean }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Permission', PermissionSchema);
```

And a Folder model with a reference to the permission document.
You can reference another schema like this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var FolderSchema = new Schema({
  name: { type: string },
  permissions: [ { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Permission' } ]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Folder', FolderSchema);
```

And then call `Folder.findOne().populate('permissions')` to ask mongoose to populate the field permissions.

Now, the following:

```
savePermission: function (folderId, permission, callback) {
    Folder.findOne({ _id: folderId }).populate('permissions').exec(function (err, data) {
        var perm = _.findWhere(data.permissions, { _id: permission._id });                

        _.extend(perm, permission);

        data.markModified("permissions");
        data.save(callback);
    });
}
```

The `perm` field will not be undefined (if the permission._id is actually in the permissions array), since it's been populated by Mongoose.

Comment: but if I did like that, I should make a separate collection for the permissions?

Comment: Yes, that's how mongoose would consider the `permissionSchema`. Each schema maps to a mongodb collection.

Comment: Uhm.. but I'm not sure I want a separate collection. Does it change something? Or is it just a logical matter?

Comment: I'll try to detail both approaches in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

just try

```
let doc = await Folder.findOneAndUpdate(
    { "_id": folderId, "permissions._id": permission._id },
    { "permissions.$": permission},
);
```