# Updating an array inside a Mongoose Model

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have to do an update on the following Mongoose Model.

```
var room_schema = new Schema({
title:          { type: String, required: true },
questions:    [{    //array of reflections
    q_index: {type: Number},
    q_text: { type: String},
    responses: [{   //array of 
        student: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
        response: { type: String }
    }]
  }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Room', room_schema);
```

Required values are in an object as

```
x = {
room: ObjectId("586a0aa0232a3918c8b7f5c9"),
student: ObjectId("5863918c85c9ba0aa0232a7f"),
question: 0,
msg: "Some Message"    
}
```

Now, i want to update the room. I tried doing something like this

```
Room.update(
  {_id:x.room, 
    'questions.q_index':x.question,
    'questions.responses.student':x.student},
  {$set:{
    'responses.$.student.response' : x.msg
  }},function(err, data){
    if(err){throw err}
    console.log(data);
  }
);
```

The msg which is being returned is `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }` and needless to say the update is not happening.
Also, there is a possibility that the `Room` may not have a response array in it. And i expect that, if that is the case, then the array should be created and then updated.
Please give me some guidance.

Comment: Your `responses.$.student.response` ==> `responses.$.response` since `student` don't have 'response' as `sub document`

Comment: Is `reflections` in your schema ?

Comment: Sorry @ShaishabRoy, I have edited the mistake in the question. It was a typo in the question.

Comment: Thanks @JyothiBabuAraja, i tried that option but its giving the same result.

Comment: I think you need two `$` positional indices, since you have nested arrays. Some thing like this `questions.$.responses.$.response`.

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja `MongoError: Too many positional (i.e. '$') elements found in path 'questions.$.responses.$.response'`

Comment: It's obvious. I think you need to use [aggreagtion](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) here

Comment: @JyothiBabuAraja Obvious? Ok. Interesting. Well! thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

Sry, but I can't write a comment since I don't have enough of rep, so I'm forced to write my notice as an answer.

I notice something in your first query when you search for a room by it's _id. Try to put _id in quotes like this "_id", because it should be like this relating to this post

[stackoverflow: updating-an-array-inside-a-mongoose-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument)

Comment: This is giving the exact same o/p: `{ ok: 0, n: 0, nModified: 0 }`

May be something else is there which i am missing.

May be i will have to write the whole deal.

Comment: Check the link I sent, mb there will be something interesting. You should also check this http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html