# Finding a subdoc by id with Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to find and update a subdoc using mongoose and mongdb but I can't seem to find the subdocs using the ids.

My schema

```
var Attending = new Schema({
   users: []
});

var Query = new Schema({
   name: [],
   url: [],
   attending: [Attending],
   img: []
});
```

Using the ids for both docs, just finding returns `null` for the doc. However, if i only using the general Id I can find the entire doc but not the subdoc.

```
 Queries.findOne(
     { "_id": queryId, "attending._id": attendingId },
      function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
        res.render('index');
     }
 );
```

sample doc

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "58d995026d7c8f0a3028a50f"
},
"img": [
    "https://pic1",
    "https://pic2"
],
"attending": [
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58d995026d7c8f0a3028a505"
        },
        "users": [
            "somebody"
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "58d995026d7c8f0a3028a506"
        },
        "users": [
            "another person"
        ]
    }
],
"url": [
    "https://www.yelp.com/2",
    "https://www.yelp.com/1"

],
"name": [
    "The Rivermill",
    "Sharkeys"
],
"__v": 0
}
```

I am using the correct ids and expect to the first subdoc in attending to be returned or whichever one is searched. Instead `null` is returned.

Queries is made like this:

```
var names = [];
var urls = [];
var imgUrls = [];
var attendingArray = [];

for (var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    names.push(businesses[i].name);
    urls.push(businesses[i].url);
    imgUrls.push(businesses[i].image_url);

    //add attending schema
    var newAttending = Attending({
          users: ["somebody"]
    });

   attendingArray.push(newAttending);
} 

var newQuery = Queries({
        name: names,
        url: urls,
        attending: attendingArray,
        img: imgUrls
});
```

Comment: When you separate by comma, you are using an AND operator, not an OR.

Comment: I want to use the AND operator though. I am looking first for the query with the id and then within that query I want to find the attending subdoc with that id. This is demonstrated in this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument

Comment: Have you verified the input values ? Can you add a sample doc that you are expecting your search to return and your expected response  ? Do you have separate collections or `Attending` documents is embedded  in `Queries` collection ?

Comment: sample doc added. The attending docs are embedded in the queries collection as shown.

Comment: I just ran your code with your data. It is giving me the data back. `var Queries  = mongoose.model('collectionname', Query);

Queries.findOne(
     { "_id": "58d995026d7c8f0a3028a50f", "attending._id": "58d995026d7c8f0a3028a505" },
      function(err, doc) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log(doc);
     }
 );`

Comment: I just ran the same thing and I get null! The only difference is that I didn't include `var Queries = mongoose.model('collectionname', Query);` but Im connecting to the database through mlab and if I remove the `attending._id` I get the full doc.

Comment: How is `Queries ` model created ?

Comment: I added query construction. Let's discuss in chat.