# How to Update Multiple Fields Inside an Array in Mongodb, Express, NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to Update Multiple Objects by Its ID inside an array? I wanted to Update the experience by its ID by the User,

Below i have attached my mongodb json object screenshot:

[image]

I can already Create an Experience by the User:

```
router.put('/experience',
    [
        auth,
        [
            check('title', 'Title is required').not().isEmpty(),
            check('company', 'Company is required').not().isEmpty(),
            check('from', 'From date is required').not().isEmpty(),
        ],
    ],
    async (req, res) => {
        const errors = validationResult(req);
        if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
            return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
        }

        const {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description,
        } = req.body;

        const newExp = {
            title,
            company,
            location,
            from,
            to,
            current,
            description,
        };

        try {
            const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
            // unshift is same with push it pushes it in the beginner rather than the end
            profile.experience.unshift(newExp);

            await profile.save();

            res.json(profile);
            console.log(req.body);
        } catch (err) {
            console.error(err.message);
            res.status(500).send('Send Error');
        }
    }
);
```

and Here is my non working code about the Update **strong text**

```
router.patch('/experience/:exp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.exp_id;
    let expId = req.body;
    try {
        const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });

        profile.experience.findOneAndUpdate(
            { id },
            { $set: { expId } },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.json(profile);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});
```

Comment: use `id` instead of `{id}` and use `{ $set:{ 'expId': expId,,,,,,,more fields if needed} }` instead of `{ $set: { expId } }` in your `findOneAndUpdate` function.

Comment: it returns profile.experience.findOneAndUpdate is not a function

my profile.experience is an array of objects btw.

user: {
        // Special field type because
        // it will be associated to different user
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user',
    },
experience: [
{ title: {        type: String,
                required: true,
            },
            company: {
type: String,
required: true,
},
            location: {
                type: String,
            },
            from: {
type: Date,
  required: true,
 },

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look around this, corrected below things:

1. from `{ id }` to `{ "experience._id": id }`
2. `{ $set: { expId } }` to `{ $set: { fields of experience } }`
3. removed `const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });`
4. from `profile.experience.findOneAndUpdate` to `Profile.findOneAndUpdate`
5. added data and error response function `(err, data)`

```
router.patch('/experience/:exp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    let id = req.params.exp_id;
    let expId = req.body;
    try {
        await Profile.findOneAndUpdate(
            { 
                "experience._id": id
            },
            { 
                $set: { 
                    'experience.$.title': req.body.title, 
                    'experience.$.company': req.body.company, 
                    'experience.$.from': req.body.from, 
                }
            },
            { new: true },
            (err, data) => {
                if (!err){
                    res.json(data);
                }else{
                    res.json(err);
                }
            }
        );
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send(err.message);
    }
});
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score -1):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762417/13199635 This should help you out. Also in your current code, where you are updating your `profile.experience`, you should probably use `{_id: id}` instead of just `{id}`. so your updated code would be like

```
profile.experience.findOneAndUpdate(
            { _id: id },
            { $set: { expId } },
            { new: true }
        );
        res.json(profile);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: It should be `{_id: id}` not `{id: id}`.

Comment: Yeah. I assumed he had his own defined id field.

Comment: it returns profile.experience.findOneAndUpdate is not a function. How can I fix this?

Comment: @JmMacatangay, Just use `Profile.findOneAndUpdate`

Comment: It returns the date but it doesn't update it. In my mongodb atlas the experience has it's own id.

I already done the delete one and here's my code:

router.delete('/experience/:exp_id', auth, async (req, res) => {
    try {
  const profile = await Profile.findOne({ user: req.user.id });
// Get removed index
const removeIndex = profile.experience
 .map((item) => item.id)
.indexOf(req.params.exp_id);

profile.experience.splice(removeIndex, 1);
await profile.save();
res.json(profile);
} catch (err) {
console.error(err.message);
res.status(500).send('Send Error'); }
});

Comment: @turivishal https://stackoverflow.com/q/62791188/11243223

Comment: @turivishal https://stackoverflow.com/q/64061393/11243223 can you help me agian?