# Cannot Update Password and Put in Postman

Tags: node.js, rest, express, postman

I get success whenever I forgot a password and it send a link for the password reset, here is my code for it.

```
router.put('/forgotpassword', async (req, res) => {
const { email } = req.body;

const errors = validationResult(req);

if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
}

try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({
            errors: [{ msg: `User with that email doesn't exist` }],
        });
    }

    const token = jwt.sign({ _id: user._id }, resetUserPassword, {
        expiresIn: '1m',
    });

    const emailData = {
        from: emailFrom,
        to: email,
        subject: 'Password Reset Link',
        html: `
        <h1> Please Click the Link to Reset your password </h1>
        <p>${PORT}/auth/resetpassword/${token}</p>`,
    };

    return User.updateOne({ resetUserPassword: token }, (err) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log('RESET PASSWORD LINK ERROR');
            return res.status(400).json({
                err: 'Error in resetting the password',
            });
        } else {
            sgMail
                .send(emailData)
                .then((sent) => {
                    // console.log('SIGNUP EMAIL SENT', sent)
                    return res.json({
                        message: `Email has been sent to ${email}. Follow the instruction to activate your account`,
                    });
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    // console.log('SIGNUP EMAIL SENT ERROR', err)
                    return res.json({
                        message: err.message,
                    });
                });
        }
    });
} catch (error) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).send('Server error');
}});
```

and I have successfully recieved it in my email.

Example: http://localhost:5000/api/auth/reset/eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJfaWQiOiI1ZjZkOTllZmFkNDRhZDNhMjBkMDYyNDQiLCJpYXQiOjE2MDEwMjM1NTUsImV4cCI6MTYwMTAyMzYxNX0.sZ0YEUwRDbgcw6O90QLSdguki0y6juCbXDiePWCX1hY

This is the link I used in postman

However, my concern is that I always get this error in postman

[image: Postman]

I know my error is in the link and I can't figure it to work. So with this problem I can't also identify if the password update is works or not. so In short I have two problems.

Here is my code for the reset password

```
router.put(
'/reset',
[
    check(
        'newPassword',
        'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 }),
],
async (req, res) => {
    const { resetPassword, newPassword } = req.body;

    const errors = validationResult(req);

    if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
        return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() });
    }

    try {
        if (resetPassword) {
            jwt.verify(resetPassword, resetUserPassword, function (err) {
                if ((err, decoded)) {
                    return res.status(400).json({
                        err: 'Expired Link. Please try again',
                    });
                }
            });
}
                User.findOne(
                    {
                        resetPassword,
                    },
                    (err, user) => {
                        if (err || !user) {
                            return res.status(400).json({
                                error: 'Something went wrong. Try later',
                            });
                        }
                    const updatedFields = {
                        password: newPassword,
                        resetPassword: '',
                    };

                    user = _.extend(User, updatedFields);

                    user.save((err, result) => {
                        if (err) {
                            return res.status(400).json({
                                error: 'Error resetting user password',
                            });
                        }
                        res.json({
                            message: `Great! Now you can login with your new password`,
                        });
                    });
                }
            );
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(err.message);
        res.status(500).send('Server error');
    }
});
```

My Route

Note: The auth route is working because I try it using get - res.send('Auth Route');

Here is my User's database

[image: User's Schema]

[image: Routes]

Answer (score 0):

The request url for the reset route contains a path parameter, i.e. the part after `/api/auth/reset`. So in order for express to be able to catch this request you need to change the route definition and add the path parameter:

```
router.put(
'/reset/:token',
[
    check(
        'newPassword',
        'Please enter a password with 6 or more characters'
    ).isLength({ min: 6 }),
], ...
```

Comment: i get this error    {
            "msg": "Please enter a password with 6 or more characters",
            "param": "newPassword",
            "location": "body"
        }

Comment: This is a new issue then, as you can see that the route is now hit...Are you sure your request contains a valid value for `newPassword` in the request body?

Comment: You won't need that because of  user = _.extend(user, updatedFields);

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. You're applying `_.extend` in completly different part of your code that has nothing to do with the `/reset` route. Also this new error has nothing to do with the original error `Cannot PUT ...` that was shown in the screenshot. This issue has been solved, so please accept this answer and post a new one or at least edit your question...