# Updating nested field in mongoose

Tags: mongoose

> this is my model

```
const DoctorSchema=mongoose.Schema({
    ds:[{day:String,timeSlots:[{time:String,status:Boolean}]}],
    hospital:{type:mongoose.Schema.ObjectId,ref:'Hospital',required:true},
    city:{type:[String],index:true},
    addedAt:{type:Date,default:Date.now}
})
```

> the ds field is the dateslot fields of the doctor. after a patient
> books a time slot then the status of that time slot of that particular
> day should be made to false so that no other patient books the same
> time slot.
>
> the ds field is an array of objects containing day field and
> timeslots array where time slots are the slots available for a
> particular day
>
> ds:[{day,that days timeslot array}]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument answers the question, showing solutions with mongoose and mongo directly. You can use the positional operator ($) or modify the document with mongoose and resave it

Comment: const doctor=await Doctor.findOneAndUpdate({"_id":docId,"ds.timeSlots._id":"5f37f980d178d528f822775d"},{  $set:{'ds.timeSlots.$.status':false}})            i tried this but getting error MongoError: Cannot create field 'timeSlots' in element {ds: [ { _id: ObjectId('5f37f980d178d528f8227750'), day: "0", timeSlots: [ { _id: ObjectId('5f37f980d178d528f8227751'), time: "4:30 PM", status: true }, { _id: ObjectId('5f37f980d178d528f8227752'), time: "5:45 PM", status: false } ] }

Comment: just the official docs  "Nested Arrays
The positional $ operator cannot be used for queries which traverse more than one array, such as queries that traverse arrays nested within other arrays, because the replacement for the $ placeholder is a single value"