# I have a Schema with Sub Schema. I want to update particular data in the Sub Schema

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb, mongoose

this is my schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose')

const MaterialListSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    nomenclature:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    national: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    partnumber:{
        type:String,
        required:true
    },
    quantity: { 
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    unit:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    }
})

const MrrlSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    aircrafttype:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    mrrlcategory:{
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    materiallist: [MaterialListSchema]
})

const Mrrl = mongoose.model('Mrrl', MrrlSchema)

module.exports = Mrrl
```

this is my update code . but it will delete all the sub document on the selected and will only have remaining

```
Mrrl.updateOne({
        'materiallist': {$elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id}}
   },{
        $set: { materiallist: req.body }
   }).then((data)=>{
       console.log(data)
   })
```

Answer (score 0):

If i understand your question, you need use arrayFilters

```
  // it is your req.body
  const newMaterial = {
    nomenclature: '2'
  };

  const result = await MrrlSchema.updateMany({ 'materiallist': {$elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id }} },
      { "$set": { "materiallist.$[material]": newMaterial } },
      { "arrayFilters": [ { "material._id": req.params.id } ] });
```

Note: arrayFilters can be use only with 3.6+ mongo

Comment: does not work either. and it will add new document rather than update

Comment: could you provide your input and expected result please ?

Comment: what is req.body for you ? array?

Comment: {
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5f69698f9ad2e0da5dc5b8e4"
    },
    "aircrafttype": "UH-1H",
    "mrrlcategory": "STRUCTURAL",
    "materiallist": [{
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f6c919bac3c1e9e7f589aaf"
        }
    }, {
        "_id": {
            "$oid": "5f6c96d7f2d41aa54a510094"
        },
        "nomenclature": "a",
        "national": "a",
        "partnumber": "a",
        "quantity": 3,
        "unit": "a",
        "price": 3
    }],
    "__v": 0
}

Comment: and could you please send me two things
1. what is req.body for you 
2. what you expect in materiallist after update

Comment: in such case you need use push without each, just $push: { materiallist: req.body }, and req.body will be added to your materiallist

Comment: Not add. the selected sub document must be updated. if I use push then it will add new document

Comment: ah , sorry. so i not understand it. You should try use arrayFilter 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/#positional-update-arrayfilters

Comment: ok, i need some time for prepare example for you, will back soon. 

btw if materiallist is not big array, it can be better just update in nodejs and just do $set , 

but you must be sure in such case that array will not contain a lot of elements

Comment: yes, but again if you not call this code often , for example customer press button few times per day and your array contain less than 20 elements for example.
-  It can be better just do with nodejs
<ul> 
1. Do find 'materiallist': {$elemMatch: { _id: req.params.id}}
2. Do map ( in nodejs ) 
3. And do set with new array 
</ul>

It is not so dramatic for small data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26156687/mongoose-find-update-subdocument. this is same with this one

Comment: what if I want to delete particular data un subdocument