# Updating a subdocument in array in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, next.js

I have two models, defined in two seperate files

```
//models/Projects.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

export const projectSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
        trim: true,
    },
    companyBackground: {
        type: String,
        required: false,
        trim: true,
    }
});
module.exports = mongoose.models.Project || mongoose.model('Project', projectSchema);
```

```
//models/User.js
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const { projectSchema } = require('./Project');

const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    projects: [{ type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Project' }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.models.User || mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I create a new user, and then create a new project, by pushing it to the user

```
import dbConnect from "utils/dbConnect";
import User from "models/User";
import Project from "models/Project";

export default async (req, res) => {
    await dbConnect();
    const { query: { id }, method } = req;

    switch (method) {
        case "POST":
            try {
                    const user = await User.findById(id);

                    if (!user) {
                        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "User not found" });
                    }

                    const newProject = new Project(req.body);
                    console.log(newProject);
                    user.projects.push(newProject);
                    await user.save();

                    if (!user) {
                        return res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: "Project not added" 
                    }
                    res.status(200).json({ data: user });

            } catch (error) {
                res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
            }
            break;
        default:
            res.status(400).json({ success: false });
            break;
    }
};
```

Bu here is the question. I can easily create a new project and save it to the user, but not make any updates.
Approaches I have tried include (but are not limited to):

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26157458/2947684
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/47762417/2947684

To demonstrate the problems, see

```
const updateString = "projects.$." + req.body.property;
    Project.findOneAndUpdate(
        { _id: req.body.projectid },
            { $set: { [updateString]: req.body.value } },
                function (error, success) {
                    if (error) {
                        console.log('error');
                        console.log(error);
                    } else {
                        console.log("success");
                        console.log(success);  //Returns null
                    }
                }
    );
```

The above returns null

And when I do this, I get

```
User.findById(userid)
    .then((user => {
        const project = user.projects.id(req.body.projectid); //user.projects.id is not a function
        project.set(newContent);
        return user.save();
        }))
        .then((user) => {
            res.send(user);
        })
            .catch((error) => {
                console.log('error: ', error.message);
                res.status(400).json({ success: false, message: error.message });
    });
```

Here is says that user.projects.id is not a function...
In mongo DB Atlas, I can see that the project has indeed been created.

This is turning me crazy, can someone tell me what I am doing wrong?
Would it be better, simply to create the projects as arrays (without making them as a mongoose object?)

Comment: Exactly what issue are you facing? Are you not able to update the sub-document? or you are not able to get projects of a user?

Comment: The default `_id` is ObjectID, not string, while fields from `req.body` are strings, so the filter `{ _id: req.body.projectid}` will never match.  Try casting the projectid to ObjectId.

Comment: @Joe can you ellaborate on what you mean by casting the projectid?

Comment: @PrashantPokhriyal In the end I just want to update the user with the new properties for the project object, and then return the whole user. But the part about updating the project is giving me a hard time.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7825700/convert-string-to-objectid-in-mongodb